# Any idea what this .NET error means?

Tags: iis-6, asp.net-2.0

I have [Bugnet](http://www.bugnetproject.com/) installed on my hosted server and it does work, seems that all functionality of the project works as one would expect.

However seems on any page render this error is generated;

> System.Configuration.
>
> ConfigurationErrorsException: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

The part that throws me is the application does function as expected. It is installed into a subdomain on a hosted server, not setup to run in a virtual directory.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, this error occurs when IIS is not configured correctly for your deployment. You state that this is installed to a subdomain on your hosted server, which at first glance indicates that this error should simply not appear. But I have to ask what URLs you are seeing it with? (Just one or two, if you don't mind.)

Normally, this error has always occurred for me when I dropped a .NET app into a directory on an IIS site, and forgot to configure that directory as a virtual directory and application correctly. As a result, some config entries which are application-level only caused the ASP.NET framework to throw your exception.

If your URLs look right, see if your host provides you direct access to IIS settings. If they do, then you can double-check all of the settings directly and ensure that they are correct.

Comment: I've just clicked around a bit, and I might be nuts, but the app seems to be working fine.

Comment: Yes thats what I am saying. It works fine, just generates these errors on every page load. The errors are mailed to me via the apps error handler. Very frustrating...

Comment: Does your app use any kind of web services or an external web application at all? Generally, this error (if it was directly thrown by your app) would prevent your app from running at all. It sounds to me like it's lower in the stack -- a web service or other external dependency.

Comment: It was a web service in a subfolder in the subdomain, once I changed the configuration for that - no more error! Genius!

Answer (score 1):

There is a web.config in your app with a section which is only allowed in the application root (or higher - i.e. machine config). Unless you have more than one web.config in your app, it is probably due to the fact that somehow the root virtual directory in your app is not configured to be a web app.

To configure it properly open property dialog for your root virtual directory in IIS control panel and click button labeled "Create Application"

Comment: The app is running, its just throwing these issues. You can see it at http://tickets.myabriza.net